# Typescript cannot infer type T properly from EventEmitter<T> param in RxJs operator (Angular app)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

[image: Sort type not recognized in resulting Observable]

When using `combineLatest` operator with sortChange property, which is of type `EventEmitter<Sort>` and pageChange which is of type `Subject<number>`, then in resulting Observable the `Sort` type is not recognized and is inferred as `unknow` (image above).

When using a little hack with mapping `this.sort.sortChange.pipe(map(sort => sort))` the value of `EventEmitter<Sort>` is inferred correctly as `Sort` (image below).

[image: Sort type inferred correctly]

It looks like to me, that `EventEmitter` is the trouble maker and TypeScript cannot figure out the type it will emit.

Can you please explain what's going on and if there is a way get a correct type without workaround?

Comment: If possible, do not include code as images.

Comment: I had to add images to get information about parameters and inferred types for `combineLatest` operator.  That only appears in VS Code, when you hover mouse over the operator...

Comment: Never noticed this myself, probably since I always use asObservable() out of habit. I guess it might be related to how the typeguards are written and the fact that EventEmitter have it's own overload for subscribe method that doesn't follow the Observable<T> pattern. Using asObservable will correctly infer type as it will infer from Observable and Subject implementation (as stupid as it sounds, it works).

Comment: Need reproducible code as it works well for me.

Comment: thanks for checking, will create a stackblitz and post here